# How to convert a grayscale image to pure black and white in php?

Tags: php, image, matlab, gd, grayscale

I'm trying to convert a grayscale image to pure black and white in PHP using the GD library.

The purpose would be to detect the cervical cells within the image.

I'll leave the PHP code and a MatLab one (I wrote this code in MatLab and I'm trying to obtain the same result in PHP). Basically, I'm having trouble accessing each individual pixel's color and modifying it. [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OInx.jpg)

PHP:

```
<?php
 $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("celule.jpg");

function imagetograyscale($im)
{
    if (imageistruecolor($im)) {
        imagetruecolortopalette($im, false, 256);
    }

    for ($c = 0; $c < imagecolorstotal($im); $c++) {
        $col = imagecolorsforindex($im, $c);
        $gray = round(0.299 * $col['red'] + 0.587 * $col['green'] + 0.114 * $col['blue']);
        imagecolorset($im, $c, $gray, $gray, $gray);
    }
}

imagetograyscale($im);

//imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -255);  //i'm not looking for this effect 

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);

$C = imagesx($im); //width
 $L = imagesy($im); //height

 echo "Dimensiuni imagine: latime $C, inaltime $L <br>";

 //scanning through the image
 for($x = 0; $x < $L; $x++) {  //each line
    for($y = 0; $y < $C; $y++) {  //each column
        // pixel color at (x, y)
        $color = imagecolorat($im, $y, $x);
        $color = imagecolorsforindex($im, $color); //getting rgb values
        $RED[$x][$y] = $color["red"];  //each rgb component
        $GREEN[$x][$y] = $color["green"];
        $BLUE[$x][$y] = $color["blue"];

    }
 } 

?>
```

MATLAB:

```
clear all, clc, close all;


I = imread('celule.jpg');
imshow(I)
title('original');

a=rgb2gray(I);

figure;
imshow(a)
title('grayscale');

s=size(a);


for i=1:s(1)
    for j=1:s(2)

        if a(i,j)>190
            a(i,j)=0;
        else a(i,j)=255;
            end
        end
end

 figure;
 imshow(a)
 title('pure black and white');
```

Comment: Having gone to the trouble of ensuring your image contains only pure black and white (i.e. 0 or 255), it seems odd that you would want to save it as a JPEG which is generally 3-channel and, because it is lossy, perfectly at liberty to change your 0/255 values in order to save space. Wouldn't you be better creating a lossless, perfect representation of your pure black and white image as a PNG?

Comment: it didn't cross my mind to convert the image to png. the data base im working with contains jpeg cell images, so i just assumed im going to work with that format. i'm also very new to processing images in php, and i have so much more to learn, but thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do that with `gd`:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -f
<?php

   // Open image and get dimensions
   $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("cellule.jpg");
   $w = imagesx($im);
   $h = imagesy($im);

   // Convert to greyscale
   imagefilter($im,IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
   imagepng($im, "grey.png");              // DEBUG only

   // Allocate a new palette image to hold the b&w output
   $out = imagecreate($w,$h);
   // Allocate b&w palette entries
   $black = imagecolorallocate($out,0,0,0);
   $white = imagecolorallocate($out,255,255,255);

   // Iterate over all pixels, thresholding to pure b&w
   for ($x = 0; $x < $w; $x++) {
      for ($y = 0; $y < $h; $y++) {
         // Get current color
         $index  = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
         $grey   = imagecolorsforindex($im, $index)['red'];
         // Set pixel white if below threshold - don't bother settting black as image is initially black anyway
         if ($grey <= 190) {
            imagesetpixel($out,$x,$y,$white);
         }
      }
   }
   imagepng($out, "result.png");
?>
```

[image]